# not all buttons work in html?

Tags: jquery, html, button, input

I have four different input type buttons. First two work while latter two don't. I have tried using button tags, a hrefs instead. The problem remains the same. The buttons have javascript functions. Regardless of the no of extra buttons I add, only the first two buttons work. Can somebody help me?

html:

```
<div id="links">
    <input type="button" id="btnHome" value="Home"/>
<input type="button" id="btnAboutme" value="About me"/>
<input type="button" id="btnPortfolio" value="Portfolio"/>
<input type="button" id="btnContact" value="Contact me"/>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#btnHome").click(function(){
    if (!(tmpNo == 1)){
        animateLeft(tmp, $home);
    }
    tmpNo = 1;
    tmp = $home;
    return false;
});

$("#btnAboutme").click(function(){
    if (!(tmpNo == 2)){
        animateLeft(tmp, $aboutme);
    }
    tmpNo = 2;
    tmp = $aboutme;
    return false;
});

$("#btnPortfolio").click(function(){
    if (!(tmpNo == 3)){
        animateLeft(tmp, $portfolio);
    }
    tmpNo = 3;
    tmp = $portfolio;
    return false;
});

$("#btnContact").click(function(){
    if (!(tmpNo == 4)){
        animateLeft(tmp, $contact);
    }
    tmpNo = 4;
    tmp = $contact;
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in your Javascript console?

Comment: what are the value of `$home` ,`$contact`, etc? You mix up PHP with JavaScript ?

Comment: What/Where is `TmpNo`?

Comment: All of your variables are global, and some of them are not defined at all ?

Comment: Have you written the above code in $(document).ready or window.onload function, because if you not do like that,then you are trying to bind event handlers when DOM is not ready

Answer (score -1):

Use On method instead of Click function because when multiple clicks are to be included,it  never works,So Change your code as

```
$(document).on( 'click','#btnPortfolio', function (e) {
if (!(tmpNo == 3)){
    animateLeft(tmp, $portfolio);
}
tmpNo = 3;
tmp = $portfolio;
return false;

});
```

Change all the click events like this...
Thank U